# Migrating from FormsAuthentication to Identity. FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity

When migrating from FormsAuthentication to Identity I have some code that have :

```
return Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
```

In Identity I don't find this configuration (also I don't know why it was on FormsAuthentication in the first place) I'm going to change to

```
return Redirect("~/");
```

Is there any Identity configuration for this scenario or is just removed that functionability from identity ?

Answer (score 0):

This is non-existing in Identity.

However when you do Identity configuration, you do stuff like this in `Auth.Config.cs`

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),

            // other stuff
         }
```

See the `LoginPath` property set? that's the redirecting address that is now working the same way as `FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl`, only you don't specify it in `web.config`.

Comment: Just assign the path to a public constant and reuse where needed